# C++ - Como passar uma string para uma classe

Tags: c++, string, classes

Estou com um probleminha quando tento passar uma string para uma classe. Resumindo: no programa principal vou ler essa string e passar para a classe:

```
cout << "----- Vamos as opcoes! -----" << endl;
cout << "(1) - Adicionar um funcionario" << endl;
.
.
.
cin >> opcao;

switch(opcao){
    case 1: //Adicionar um funcionario
        Funcionario funcionario_novo;
        empresa1.adicionaFuncionario(funcionario_novo);


}
```

Tenho uma classe chamada Funcionario, que contem o nome dele, o salário e a data de admissão.

```
void
Empresa::adicionaFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario_novo){
   m_totalFuncionarios++;

   string _nome_, _data_;
   float _salario_;

   cout << "Nome: " << endl;
   getline(cin,_nome_);
   funcionario_novo.setNome(_nome_);

   cout << "Salario: " << endl;
   cin >> _salario_;
   funcionario_novo.setSalario(_salario_);

   cout << "Data de admissao: " << endl;
   getline(cin,_data_);
   funcionario_novo.setData(_data_);

   m_funcionarios[m_totalFuncionarios] = funcionario_novo;      //Guardo meu funcionário novo no vetor
}
```

Quando eu rodo, ele funciona até `m_totalFuncionarios++;`, mas não passa essas strings pro funcionário.

```
void
Funcionario::setNome(const string nome_){
   m_nome = nome_;
}

void
Funcionario::setSalario(float salario_){
   m_salario = salario_;
}
```

Deveria guardar, mas não guarda.

Minha dúvida é: qual seria a melhor maneira de passar essa minha string pra classe?

Comment: Como você sabe que não guardou o valor? Já verificou se por acaso não seria a função `getline` que não está fazendo o trabalho que deveria fazer?

Comment: Na verdade eu não consigo ler. Quando eu rodo não tem a opção pra eu escrever, ele pula. Utilizei o getline separado e funcionou.

Comment: Então não entendi seu problema nem sua solução o.O Mas fico feliz que tenha solucionado

Comment: Não funcionou. Eu usei separado pra ser se funcionava com outras coisas, e funciona. Mas nesse caso não funcionou. Gostaria de poder submeter o código todo, mas ficaria muito grande. Acho que vou excluir, não vou conseguir mostrar o erro.

Comment: Já experimentou com `cin.ignore();` antes do `getline` e depois de ler com `cin>>` ? Começo por dizer que essas duas formas de leitura não se misturam muito bem